# Insert / add / push array of an objects into Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am trying to insert an array of objects into an object, so far I search but I was not able to find such what exactly I am looking for.

```
    myArray = [ { name: 'TS', width: '11', height: '2', order: 3 },
           { name: 'TS', width: '11',height: '2',order: 3 } ]
```

is there any function available which I can use to add/push the above array into an object

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I am adding the array of an objects into  object ( which exist already in Mongodb), I am accesing the db object, but not able to insert an array in that object

Comment: `Object.assign(yourObject, { myArray })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bracket (myObject['arrayName']), or dot notation (myObject.arrayName)  to assign the array to an object property, for example:

```js
const myObject = { id: 42, name: 'myObject' };

const myArray = [ { name: 'TS', width: '11', height: '2', order: 3 },
           { name: 'TS', width: '11',height: '2',order: 3 } ]
           
const arrayName = 'myArray';
myObject[arrayName] = myArray;

console.log('myObject:', myObject);
```